# Symfony app on subdomain auto login user based on session variables from main domain

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony-3.3

We have a Symfony application on a subdomain that we have added to our main domain (not a Symfony app) in an iframe. We are able to pull the session variables from the main domain into the subdomain and we are looking to automatically login a user based on those session variables.

We are trying to use the `x-auth-token` based authentication to bypass the login by overriding the default login methods.

It's expected to automatically log a user into the Symfony app.

Error Message:

> The service "security.authentication.provider.guard.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service
>   "UserBundle\Security\TokenAuthenticator".

Comment: so what's the question? The error message is quite clear imho.

Answer (score -1):

@jakumi service is defined in services.yml but still, it shows non-existent.

Comment: Hi. If this is a reply to jakumi's comment, you should answer as with a new comment below, not an Answer, as this is not an answer to the original post.